# How to convert date from one timezone to another timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, date-fns

I have a date which is the beginning of a given day in the user's browser timezone but I need to convert it to the beginning of the day in another timezone, using date-fns.

I have a date:

```
const date = new Date("2020-10-13"); // Tue Oct 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

And I need to convert it to the beginning of the day in the `"America/Chicago"` timezone.

```
const timeZone = "America/Chicago";
// Need to convert a date object
// Tue Oct 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
// to
// Tue Oct 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
// and all I'm given is the timeZone value.
```

Comment: By spec, `new Date("2020-10-13")` will parse as UTC midnight - not midnight local time.  Which browser are you using?  (my guess is Safari?)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint—Safari 14 seems to have finally fixed its parser for date–only and no timezone forms ('2020-01-01' and '2020-01-01T00:00:00'), but of course older versions abound… ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get time zone support for date-fns, you will need the [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) add-on module.

Then you can do the following:

```
import { zonedTimeToUtc } from 'date-fns-tz';

const dt = zonedTimeToUtc('2020-10-13', 'America/Chicago');
```

The result will be a `Date` object that represents midnight in the given time zone.

Keep in mind that `Date` objects themselves are *always* UTC-based.  Thus, you can't get a `Date` object that is "in" a different time zone.

Also, you should pass a string into the `zonedTimeToUtc` function as shown.  You should *not* pass it to the `Date` object.  As mentioned in comments, the ECMAScript spec says that a date-only string value should be parsed *as UTC*.  However, there are still some implementations that don't follow the spec correctly.  Thus, you should avoid parsing strings using the `Date` object constructor.